# Facebook Like Button Missing after liking the url

Tags: facebook

I am currently using Floating Vertical Bar from Adthis For Sharing URL.

At first, everything appears to be correct but when i like a page using Facebook like button and reloads the page, the like button appears to be missing. There is no like button in that space.

When i move on to a new page which i have not liked the button will be there. Issue happens only when i like the page or url.

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: You should contact the maker of the plugin you're using; it's difficult for us to debug anything if it's not your code; it's probably something like multiple calls of FB.init() in the javascript SDK interfering with each other but we can't really tell if you don't have the code